# Understanding binary subtypes in BSON: what is a "function" (\x01) and what possible user defined subtypes are there?

Tags: mongodb, bson

[bsonspec.org](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) lists a set of binary subtypes, including generic binary (\x00), function (\x01), UUID (\x04), MD5 (\x05), user defined (\x80).
The questions are:

1. What is the "function" subtype and what is it used for? If this is a compiled bytecode, are there any restrictions on it? Is it used in MongoDB?
2. What user defined subtypes are there? The grammar says it is only \x80, but the notes at the bottom add that any subtype in the range \x80-\xFF is user defined. I tried reactivemongo previously, and it failed to parse any user defined type except \x80. Some googling demonstrates that, for example, perl mongodb library also knows only about \x80 and not about others. So, is that a bug, that libraries do not support \x81-\xFF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) IIRC, subtype 1 isn't used in MongoDB.  It perhaps should be deprecated.  I can't remember its history if someone does please comment otherwise I think it is ancient.

2) The spec document could be more clear, 0x80 - 0xff are all legal and that range is reserved for user defined subtypes.  Or rather less than 0x80 is reserved for predefined types.

Generally speaking, currently, MongoDB doesn't do anything semantically with the BinData subtypes, it considers them user data.  (Other than if the subtypes vary, two BinData values are then definitely not considered equal by the server for query purposes.)  Also the shell has some ability to pretty-print MD5 and UUID and helpers for those, I believe.

That said, it makes perfect sense to use BSON ex-Mongo for anything where you need to serialize some data especially if somewhat dynamically typed, and tools should expect the values to be something reasonable if of a subtype that implies that (e.g. a UUID subtype should be 16 byte value even though MongoDB server would not really care about that currently).

If a tool doesn't allow > 0x80 it probably needs tweaking.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "ex-Mongo"?

Comment: sorry.  meant "non-MongoDB uses."  ex in the latin sense.

Comment: Yes, my intent is exactly to store and exchange data in BSON both inside Mongo and outside of it. But now I am not sure I want to use BSON, because of this uncertainty in the binary subtypes and a lack of support. My question in BSON google group is also not answered.

**UPD**: anyway, thank you for the discussion, I will mark your answer accepted

Comment: The idea is that the subtype is an application defined value that the application uses, not the database.  So "lack of support" is intentional.  It's an annotation basically.

Comment: I read the post in google groups which pointed to stack overflow and then answered it here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

FYI note that subtype `0x03` is mentioned in this document, as a legacy UUID type: https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-best-practices-uuid-data/